# Old action Window is getting updated with the new action window's data in Gxt

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have an split button named "Types" with values "View", "Chart". When i click on view, i will be creating a new instance of action window and i will be setting the westwidget with view data. Now when i click on chart, i will be setting the westwidget with chart data. Now, the issue is, view action window is getting updated with chart data. I am using the same store to populate the data. But using the store, i am creating a separate tree to populate in the westwidget. Can you please help me ?

Comment: We'll need more than that description to be able to help: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)